# I have a lot of keywords

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords

I have 100 000 keywords on my website. But I can't put them in meta keywords tag, so I make a function who displays 20 keywords in the footer of my website, "randomly" for each "refresh of page". so like that Google can see them for each reloading of my pages. Each refresh page, gives him 20 other keywords.

And I add a link for each keyword to the same content with each different URL, so I create a duplicate content.

Can you give me a better solution for using all my 100 000 keywords, without using duplicate content?

Comment: Your so gonna get hammered by Google. By populating the page with keywords in the footer you are essentially keyword stuffing your pages unnecessary. Google does not require the keyword meta tag nor does it need keywords being used in the footer. It can establish and associate relevant keywords by reading your content... You don't need to force feed Google with metas or footer tactics.

Comment: I'm okay with what you say, but I need to put my 100,000 keywords for the site of my company. what can I do if I want it to be linked to the city, region, postal code, country, language, industry, employee names, and it has many diverse activity I have to put all of them on the site, and also I have to put all the works done in detail. all this gave me 100,000 keywords, I do not know where to put them. what will be your best way to proceed

Answer (score 3):

Your website doesn't have 100,000 keywords. Your *pages* have *X* number of keywords. Google isn't ranking your entire website. They're ranking each *page*. Thus your meta keywords (which aren't used for ranking purposes anymore and haven't been for a very long time) should focus on the keywords for that *page*. It should **not** be the keywords for the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have 100000 keywords on my website. But I can't put them in Meta keyword tag
```

Google doesn’t use the keywords meta tag in web search. [Here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/) is the news from Matt Cutts.

If you make a function that displays 20 keywords in the footer of our website, "randomly" for each "refresh of page", Google will consider it as [Keyword stuffing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358?hl=en). So it will negatively impact your website.

Why your are stuffing your 100000 keywords using some `functions`? rather create a page with your contents and let Google to know your keywords. but don't write content for keywords and only for users and don't duplicate your contents. So if you have a useful website for your visitors then you no need to worry about your 100000 keywords

Comment: I'm okay with what you say, but I need to put my 100,000 keywords for the site of my company. what can I do if I want it to be linked to the city, region, postal code, country, language, industry, employee names, and it has many diverse activity I have to put all of them on the site, and also I have to put all the works done in detail. all this gave me 100,000 keywords, I do not know where to put them. 
what will be your best way to proceed

Comment: @user3134277 If you have more doubts in targeting multiple keywords take a look at this page http://moz.com/blog/keyword-targeting-how-to-employ-multiple-keywords-for-seo-conversions

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the best way to proceed, I would say (if you insist):

Create unique and compelling content with the keywords (put 2-4 per content) and create content for all the 10,000 of them (you may hire content writers for the same) and put them on your website.

If you want to proceed with the way you just said (even after knowing all the SEO unfriendliness of that method) and you are looking for methods just to overcome the duplicate content trouble, I would say:

1. Put a 301 redirect to the same and and/or
2. Add a `rel="canonical"` tag to the content.